# Create virtual smart card from physical card

Tags: windows-10, smartcard

Would it be possible to "clone" a physical smart card into a virtual smart card, by using tpmvscmgr.exe utility?

I have several users in our organization that should use the same certificates contained in the physical smart card.

Comment: This would break all of the security of using a smart card.  You can create virtual cards or physical cards but you can’t and/or (shouldn’t) clone a physical smart card

Comment: Overall the whole idea of several people sharing a single certificate seems a bit odd. Doesn't the system let you authorize multiple certificates?

Answer (score 2):

Private keys cannot be extracted from a smartcard; indeed this is *the whole point* of smartcards.

(Although they don't offer nearly as much physical protection as e.g. USB tokens, but it'd still be quite a lot of work and equipment which you do not have; in short, it's impractical. Unless you're using an IDPrime or another model that's vulnerable to the recently published ROCA attack...)

---

However, if your CA allows it, you can issue a **new** certificate with its private key generated *on a computer*, then install that certificate & keypair to as many smartcards as you want.

Comment: I'm aware of the the point of smartcards, but I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't possible to use a virtual card so I don't have the physical one, going from user to user.
Your suggestion however looks like a feasible option, I'll try something on that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

All the comments about whether or not this should be done, are well meaning. That being said, you didn't ask whether or not it should be, only if it could be. Whether or not it should is up to you. Not all certificates serve the same purposes. It seems most of the Should/shouldn't arguments revolve around non-repudiation. If all you are trying to accomplish is authentication then there's no reason you shouldn't do this. Multifactor authentication could still be accomplished with the setup you're asking about. You would just need to introduce another factor. Not every situation requires "something  you have," and "something you know."

In addition to this, not all systems have the same level of sensitivity, and don't require the level of security that other systems do. Kiosks, single-purpose systems, etc that provide information for the public, and have no sensitive data, yet still need to meet a security requirement in the organization's policy might benefit from this. And it would still be more secure than NOT doing it. Grey areas exist within information security. The goal is to make things as secure as you can with as little loss to functionality and availability as possible.

To answer your question, yes.. However, it depends on how "smart" the smart card is. Many modern EMV smart cards that are used for non-repudiation, authentication, email, etc have chips with built-in security features that will "flag" a private key if it's duplicated. These have been cloned, but it requires tools and skills that are not easily acquired. These are not off the shelf tools or software. Or even hardware. It would be logistically prohibitive in my opinion, and much easier to just find another solution.